# microPython Formating a number without float

Tags: python, micropython

I don't have the luxury of floating point precision and are very limited on code space / ram / speed etc.

```
TMP = 2562
DEG = str(int(TMP/100))+'.'+str(TMP % 100)
print(DEG)
>> 25.62
```

Is there a more pythionc way of achieving this formatting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly. But a more pythonic way to format the number to a .2 decimal string would be:

```
TMP = 2562
DEG = "{:.2f}".format(TMP/100)
print(DEG)
>> 25.62
```

Edit 2021:
Or when using python3.6 or higher:

```
TMP = 2562
DEG = f"{TMP/100:.2f}"
print(DEG)
>> 25.62
```

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: is it? this still implies using a float

Answer (score 0):

```
TMP = 2562
float(TMP)/100
>>> 25.62
```

Does that answer your question?
here's the reference : https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/reference/asm_thumb2_float.html#convert-between-integer-and-float

Comment: Your link is to the inline assembler syntax, which doesn't seem directly relevant.